# Blank row is not visible in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I am binding an `ObservableCollection` to a DataGrid, and I want to be able to add items in the observablecollection through the blank rows.  However, when the list is empty at run time, this blank row is not showing up.  I have looked up this problem, I have `CanUserAddRows=true`, I have `IsReadOnly=false`, and I have set the datagrid's datacontext to the observable collection, and I have an empty constructor and it is still not working.  Here is what I have so far:

In XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CostCenterListViewSource}}" Name="costCenterListDataGrid" VerticalAlignment CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Cost Center" Width="102" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="glCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=GlCode, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Gl Code" Width="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="costCenterPercentageColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=CostCenterPercentage, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="%" Width="30" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my code behind I have this:

```
costCenterListDataGrid.DataContext = item.CostCenterList;
//when "item" was instantiated, it also created a new instance: costCenterList = new ObservableCollection<CostCenter>();
```

and in the CostCenter class I have:

```
public CostCenter()
{
}

public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || !Name.Equals(value))
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string GlCode
    {
        get { return glCode; }
        set 
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(GlCode) || !GlCode.Equals(value))
            {
                glCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GlCode");
            }
        }
    }

    public double CostCenterPercentage
    {
        get { return cPercentage; }
        set
        {
            if (CostCenterPercentage != value)
            {
                cPercentage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CostCenterPercentage");
            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:  This is what I have in my Window.Resources**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="jobItemViewSource1" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance my:JobItem, CreateList=True}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="jobItemNotesHistoryViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=NotesHistory, Source={StaticResource jobItemViewSource1}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CostCenterListViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=CostCenterList, Source={StaticResource jobItemViewSource1}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CostCenterListAfesViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Afes, Source={StaticResource CostCenterListViewSource}}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Hmm, the ItemsSource for the DataGrid is bound to a collection view (which is not declared in the DataGrid's Resourcess) and you are setting the DataGrid's DataContext to be the collection? Unless your actual code is slightly different I don't think anything should ever appear in the datagrid?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I forgot to add my resources.  Please check my edit

Comment: Ah, how do you populate the jobItemViewSource1 collection view at runtime?

Comment: I set my base.datacontext to the current jobitem.  The jobItem part works and populates correctly, so I know for sure there is nothing wrong there.  What is not working is the addition of a CostCenter item within that specific DataGrid.

Comment: Hmm, by the 'base datacontext' do you mean something like the window this DataGrid appears on? This would make other bindings to properties directly on the jobItem work fine, I imagine. Do existing Cost Centres get displyed, or items from the jobItemNotesHistoryViewSource collection view?